# Do elements created with document.createElement stay in memory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi, I'm slowly making a chrome extension, and I need to parse some data that contains html entities, and I need to decode it. I saw in an answer here that I could use `document.createElement` for it, so I did this:

```js
htmlDecode: function(input) {
    if(/[<>]/.test(input)) { // To avoid creating tags like <script> :s
        return "Invalid Input";
    }
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

However I'm worried that `document.createElement` leaves elements behind because this function runs on the background script, so it's not like it gets refreshed often, and it runs around 35000 times every 5 minutes.

So, do elements created by `document.createElement` get freed, or do they stay?
I mean, I do not append them anywhere and they are assiged to a local variable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sure, nothing references the div anymore after the function is ran, so it will be eventually garbage-collected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They will be garbage collected. In particular, since you're developing a Chrome extension, V8 tends to recycle temporaries like this very quickly so it shouldn't be much of a concern.

If you are worried about this in general, one common solution is to simply keep a single div around to do the job.

Comment: I guess you are right, I was just wondering if the element created could get stuck somewhere in the document. I wanted to avoid creating a div, however it might be even better because literally, it gets called over 35k times, and maybe creating element after element is worse even if they get collected.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, creating a single div and re-using it would probably be more efficient. I can't say for sure because Chrome might be smart enough to have a div lying around ready for you in the event that it determines you create them often. If you create an element with `document.createElement`, it won't be appended to the document unless you explicitly do so, so as soon as your function returns here, it has 0 references remaining and since it was function local and not referred elsewhere, V8 will reclaim it immediately, IIRC.