# Rendered SVG image in browser: copy element names to clipboard

Tags: javascript, svg, graphviz

On this webpage: http://viz-js.com/ we see a graph being rendered from a text file.

If you hover the mouse over one of the graph elements, its label appears in a pop-up. ('start' in this example)

[image]

**Question: Is there anyway to either make the label selectable or add some JavaScript to allow the text of the pop-up to be copied to the clipboard?**

My implementation of this has long node names (up to 44 chars) that I'd like to be able to copy somehow.

Thanks.

**Edit: Actions tried so far.**

Using Chrome's 'inspect' option, I see that the nodes in the SVG appear to have the class name of 'node, so I tried the following JavaScript but it had no effect:

```
$('.big').hover(function () {
    // will not work, no user action
  $('input').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});

$('.big').mousedown(function () {
    //works
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

and I can't seem to use any CSS styling to affect the look of the graph.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a look at the SVG, you can see that the hover card's text comes from the `<title>` DOM element of each shape's respective group. You can tell by editing the DOM and modifying one of the titles: you'll see a your new text when you hover over the shape.

So, we just have to grab the text from in there and [send it to the clipboard](https://techoverflow.net/2018/03/30/copying-strings-to-the-clipboard-using-pure-javascript/).

**EDIT:** This should now be a lot easier to run. It just has to wait until the `g.graph` element of the SVG is loaded to the page, instead of each time it renders.

```js
(function addListener() {
  // This time, add the listener to the graph itself
  document.querySelector('.graph').addEventListener('click', event => {
    let str = ""
    // Grab all the siblings of the element that was actually clicked on
    for (const sibling of event.target.parentElement.children) {
      // Check if they're the title
      if (sibling.nodeName != 'title') continue;
      str = sibling.innerHTML;
      break;
    }

    const ta = document.createElement('textarea');
    ta.value = str;
    ta.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    ta.style = { position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' };
    document.body.appendChild(ta);
    ta.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(ta);

    if (str == "") console.log('Nothing found to copy!');
    else console.log(`"${str}" copied to clipboard!`);
  });
})();
```

If you want to put this on the source code for the page, instead of pasting to the Chrome console, then get rid of the function declaration and take it out of the brackets. It will juts run when the file its in gets loaded.

---

**Original solution:**

```js
// Function wrapped in brackets and called immediately after declaration
// (so that it can be run from the Chrome console):
(function addListeners() {
  // Grab every SVG 'group' in the 'graph' group:
  for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.graph g')) {
    // Tell each group to listen for a click on itself:
    el.addEventListener('click', event => {
      // Create an empty string variable to store the title in
      let str = "";
      // Loop through all the elements in the group for one called 'title'
      for (const child of el.children) {
        if (child.nodeName != 'title') continue;
        // Store that title
        str = child.innerHTML;
      }

      // Copy the string to the clipboard (see link above)
      const ta = document.createElement('textarea');
      ta.value = str;
      ta.setAttribute('readonly', '');
      ta.style = { position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' };
      document.body.appendChild(ta);
      ta.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(ta);

      console.log(`"${str}" copied to clipboard!`);
    });
  }
})();
```

I tested this in the Chrome dev console of the page you linked, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I may not be able to test this until Monday when I’m back at work.

Comment: I can't get this to work - I added your code to the <script> section of my own page and also tried to save the source of the Viz-js page and add it to that, but that didn't render at all. How did you try it on the Viz-js.com page? (Sorry - very new to JavaScript).

Comment: I copied that code block into the Console tab of the Chrome developer tools. It seems that their site uses some funky importing that makes it difficult to save locally. Note that this works by adding listeners to all groups in the SVG -- that means if you run this function before the SVG groups appear, they won't get the listeners added. Let me see if I can modify it to be a single event listener on the graph element... I've also added some comments to my code.

Comment: @SteveIves See my updated solution. Keep me posted.

Comment: Nice idea. However this would create lots of `textarea`s. Maybe creating an input type hidden on the html and reset it's value on click would be a better option

Comment: @enxaneta true. I think simply moving the declaration for `ta` outside of the event listener, making sure only one would be created, is probably the quickest fix.

Comment: @enxaneta looks like we have nothing to worry about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320939/10549827

Comment: I added this inside <head><script>...</script></head> in my web page, but it doesn't work. :(  Has anyone else gotten it to work?

Comment: @chrispitude this code relies on the specific layout of the page Steve was working with. You may have to adapt it to your own site. I hope my comments are good enough to explain how I got it to work, but if your SVGs don't use the `<title>` element, you may have some more work cut out for you. I think it may be a good idea to post a separate question. Feel free to @ me if you do.